# Higher-level than socket functions with Python?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I'm doing a client/server communication with Python `socket`:

```
for i in range(10):
    connection.send(f"{i} and some other data\n".encode())  # real data is more complex
connection.send(b"OK, finished")
```

On the other side, I receive it with:

```
while True:
    res = clientsocket.recv(16384)
    if not res or res == b"OK, finished":        # doesn't always work
        break
     print(res)
```

The problem is that sometimes the received data is `"1234 and some other data\nOK, finished"` (then the previous condition doesn't work), and sometimes `"OK, finished"` on its own.

More generally, it is not very handy to have to receive an arbitrary size (here 16 KB), and assemble the potentially multiple parts, and to test if some ending condition is met.

**Is there a way to have a higher level access to the `socket` functions, allowing multi-line data, multi-part binary data to be sent/received with `socket`?**

Note: I want to keep the stateful aspect of a TCP `socket`, with a handler that lasts for the whole time of the client connection - thus I cannot use a HTTP server (which is stateless).

Comment: `data.endwswith("Ok, finished")` or something like that isnt good enough? you could use websockets ... those i think guarantee each payload resolves individually ... I think

Comment: [Here's all the existing higher-level protocols](https://docs.python.org/3/library/internet.html) that python supports out of the box. If none of those work for you then you can define your own. It would take only a handful of lines of code to implement a "record" protocol that prefixes every record with a 4-byte (32 bits) counter of the number of bytes in the record that follows. It would be quite simple to send and receive such records.

Comment: *"Is there a way ..."* - I'm not sure what you are asking. Do you want to know if this can be done in principle - of course, for example it is implemented within SMTP (line based) or Websockets (message based) protocols but also adding a TLS layer makes it kind of message based. Do you want to know how to implement something like this yourself: follow the advice in the other comment about simply prefixing each message with its length.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich SMTP is line-based, do you mean they have to escape `\n`, `\r`, etc.? What's the benefit of this line-based solution or the multipart boundary "trick" for binary data, compared to the simple size/number of bytes prefix solution? (as mentioned by PresidentJamesK.Polk)

Comment: @Basj: SMTP, HTTP/1 etc come from a time where "human-readable" was part of the expectation in protocol design, leading to text-based protocols with newline as separator between "messages" . Personally I see no benefit in this, it only makes things more complicate.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich so for a new protocol today similar to SMTP, based on low-level `socket`, you would choose bytes-size prefix for messages, and no more newline separators, and no more things like `boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p`?

Comment: @Basj: This boundary thing (multi-part MIME) is just a hack so that multi-part mails are backward compatible to the older mail format (text based, limited line length). Unless there are such restrictions I would never design a protocol like this, since this is just an nightmare to handle properly. Go binary instead where each variable sized-message is prefixed by a fixed-size length.